# $numberlong format for dates when pulling from getMongo Processor

Tags: mongodb, datetime, apache-nifi

We are using the getMongo processor to pull data from mongodb. Everything works fine but all dates are coming in the following format:

```
"$numberLong" : "1542271444000"
```

How can I get the **date as a string or date**. There doesn't seem to be a straight forward way to do the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In GetMongo configuration, go to properties and change the value of JSON Type to Standard JSON.